# Creating a new Kubernetes Object from within a Mutating Admission Controller

Tags: go, kubernetes

Can a Mutating Admission Controller update/create another Object by connecting to api-server ? I see that we can use JSON Patch to mutate the inbound object via Admission Review, but can I extend it to create a completely different object ?
Thanks!!
-Sreeni

Comment: You could build the capability into your controller sure.

Comment: Sure, JSON Patch support `remove` operation.

Comment: @menya what if I have to create a new object instead of removing.. ? Also I want to read a specific config-map contents prior to generating the json-patch..   I have the mutating webhook in Go and is running - it gets the admission Review object, I am able to walk thru get information.. but I want to read the attached config-map object and take some actions based on the contents of the config-map.  Do I have to call into a separate REST service to ge tthose or is there a way from within the Webhook, I tried config.LoadKubeConfig and is errroring.

Comment: You need to get target config-map from a k8s client. Webhook is just a web server.

Comment: I had to use the config.InClusterConfig. But I am stuck with the webhook being able to talk to the API Server as I get a 403. Looks like its a known issue. Adding SA header info seem to work for some, but Im still getting the same 403 errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mutatingwebhookconfigurations which basically hooks a service to the mutating admission controller. That's how istio inject a sidecar proxy to all the pods which has istio-injection enabled.

You can refer to the following link [Sidecar Injection Webhook](https://istio.io/docs/ops/setup/injection/)